# Shopify javascript Close Accordion on Clic

Tags: javascript, tabs, shopify, accordion

I'm customizing a Shopify store using Archetype Themes Motion v8.0.2. I have found a code to add tabs to my product pages. I've added media queries to my theme.css to display the tabs as an accordion at certain breakpoints. I would like to add code to close the accordion on click. I'm okay with HTML/CSS, but don't know any JS. I found the script online. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.shopify-tabs > li').click(function(){
      var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

      $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('current');
      $('.shopify-tab-content').removeClass('current');

      $(this).addClass('current');
      $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
  })
```

```css
.section-tab-head {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px),
  (min-width: 1051px) {
  .section-tab-head {
    background: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: inherit;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.section-tab-head.current {
  background: #dbdbdb;
  color: #333;
}
.shopify-tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shopify-tab-content > p {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.shopify-tab-content.current {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.shopify-tab-content > ul {
  list-style: disc;
}

.shopify-tab-content > ul ul {
  list-style: circle;
}

li,
.shopify-tab-content {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.shopify-tabs .shopify-tab-content {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="shopify-tabs">
  <li class="section-tab-head current" data-tab="section-tab-1"> Heading 1</li>
  <div id="section-tab-1" class="shopify-tab-content current">
    <p>some content goes here</p>
  </div>

  <li class="section-tab-head" data-tab="section-tab-2"> Heading 2</li>
  <div id="section-tab-2" class="shopify-tab-content">
    <p>more content in this tab</p>
  </div>

  <li class="section-tab-head" data-tab="section-tab-3"> Heading 3</li>
  <div id="section-tab-3" class="shopify-tab-content">
    <p>some content is in list form:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>product feature</li>
      <li>product feature</li>
      <li>product feature</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add close button to each tab and add jquery code.

```
$('ul.shopify-tabs > li .close').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to answer! 
I really have no understanding of js, and just copy pasted the original code. I'm not sure how your code works, so I have a couple of follow up questions:
When you say add a close button to each tab, do you mean a bootstrap button with class "close"? Is this wrapped in the li heading or in the div content for each tab?
Where exactly should your code be pasted in the js? I've tried a few locations, but there's no change in the output. 
Thanks!